Help with auto pro rig symmetry weight paint problem
So I tried to mirror the right hand, but they didn't match up. I used the addon Easy Weights. I don't want to weight paint each finger of the right hand individually. How can I fix this?



please also add picture As an example.


I would check the Issues page on the addon's github page or see if you can contact their support system. We can't really help with addon-related issues, only built in Blender functionality.

Have a look at the documentation:

Mirroring only works when the object’s rest pose is perfectly
symmetrical across the X axis.

The problem is that your model is not perfectly symmetrical because the scale is non-uniform, negative and not applied. Before you do rigging and weight painting you should Ctrl+A Apply > Scale and Rotation.

To fix the symmetry

apply the Scale and Rotation to the hands, upper body, head, hair, etc.
because the scale on the hands was negative their faces are flipped now and you need to fix this, too. Go to Edit mode, select all (A), and do a Recalculate Outside (Shift+N)
the Thickness of the Solidify modifier that creates the outline depends on the model's size. You need to adjust it after you applied the scale. Try 0.03 m instead of the 0.15 m.
to fix the symmetry of the hands, apply the Location to set the origin to (0,0,0). Then delete the right hand (left side), and add & apply a Mirror modifier to recreate it - "perfectly symmetrical" ;-)

Now you can select the vertices of the right thumb (=target), select the vertex group c_thumb3.l (left thumb=source), and mirror the weights with the menu item Mirror Vertex Group of the vertex group drop-down menu. I haven't tried the Easy Weights add-on, but I'm confident that it will also work now.
